# Change the position of custom uitableviewcell content in different orientations

Tags: ipad, ios5, uitableview, customization

Hi currently am working on a ipad app where i need to display the tableview. So we are displaying the tableview with a custom cell.Now the problem is when the application is in landscape mode there is a layout in my custom cell and when the app rotates to portrait mode the layout should be changed.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        //your code for landscape
    } else {
        //your code for portrait
    } 
}
```

this may helps you.....

Comment: Yes we tried it, but reloading the tableview causes in lossing the content right. for example am tapping the button on a cell to expand the cell after that if we rotate and reloadtabledata. :(